# Adjusting space between array rows and columns

Tags: spacing, lyx, arrays

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
% ...
\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x(1) & = & \frac{x(0)}{1} & = & x(0)\\
x(2) & = & \frac{x(1)}{2} & = & \frac{x(0)}{2}\\
x(3) & = & \frac{x(2)}{3} & = & \frac{x(0)}{2.3}\\
x(4) & = & \frac{x(3)}{4} & = & \frac{x(0)}{4!}\\
 &  &  &  & \vdots\\
x(n) & = & \frac{x(n-1)}{n} & = & \frac{x(0)}{n!}
\end{array}
\]
% ...
\end{document}
```

Because of the fractions in the array cells, array elements are vertically too close to each other, they are literally touching to each other. Also the horizontal spacing is too much as you see in the image (screen shot from the output PDF file).

How do I make these cell-spacings look better?

Comment: You can also add increase/decrease space between rows by supplying a positive/negative argument to `\\ `, i.e. `\\[2pt]` and `\\[-2pt]` resp. add/remove 2pt of vertical space.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x(n-1)/n` in the middle column, not `x(n-1)/n!`

Comment: Related question: [spacing - Column and row padding in tables - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
% ...
\[\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x(1) & = & \dfrac{x(0)}{1} & = & x(0)\\
x(2) & = & \dfrac{x(1)}{2} & = & \dfrac{x(0)}{2}\\
x(3) & = & \dfrac{x(2)}{3} & = & \dfrac{x(0)}{2.3}\\
x(4) & = & \dfrac{x(3)}{4} & = & \dfrac{x(0)}{4!}\\
 &  &  &  & \vdots\\
x(n) & = & \dfrac{x(n-1)}{n!} & = & \dfrac{x(0)}{n!}
\end{array}
\]
% ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

or for a left aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
% ...
\[\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}
\begin{array}{rll}
x(1) &= \dfrac{x(0)}{1} &= x(0)\\
x(2) &= \dfrac{x(1)}{2} &= \dfrac{x(0)}{2}\\
x(3) &= \dfrac{x(2)}{3} &= \dfrac{x(0)}{2.3}\\
x(4) &= \dfrac{x(3)}{4} &= \dfrac{x(0)}{4!}\\
     &                  & \vdots\\
x(n) &= \dfrac{x(n-1)}{n!} &= \dfrac{x(0)}{n!}
\end{array}
\]
% ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried applying your solution. It gives "Undefined control sequence." error on the `dfrac` commands. When I convert `dfrac`s back to `frac`s the cells are separated as in your answer. I couldn't add the `\usepackage{amsmath}` command in my code, because LyX doesn't let me edit the source code. Could this error with `dfrac` be because of that? How should I do?

Comment: In `Menu > Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble` I added `\usepackage{amsmath}` in that large text box. Now when I try to preview my code in PDF it says `LaTeX Error: 'amsmath.sty' not found.`. I'm stuck, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @hkBattousai Herbert's solution might not work except when putting the whole "array" environment into an ERT/TeX code. Probably you want it to work with the "array" environment provided by LyX. It seems not possible to use `{` and `}` in a math environment without making a global def. Hence, you can move the part `\arraycol....etch{2.2}` outside of the math environment. As ERT put `{\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}` (note the opening `{`) before the math environment and put `}` as ERT after the math environment. The opening `{` and the closing `}` will keep the change local. Working?

Comment: @hkBattousai If you want to tell LyX to definitely use the `amsmath` package go to `Document > Settings... > Math Options` deselect the "automatically usage" and select the other one.

Comment: @e-birk: You can have _everything_ inside the ERT mode! And `\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}` will be enough. But without the LyX code I cannot say why it dosn't work for him

Comment: @Herbert As I said putting everything into ERT is no problem. But how to use your approach while using the built-in "array" environment of LyX at the same time?

Comment: @e-birk: Open math-Display math and before inserting the matrix (array) hit `ctrl-L` and insert `\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}`. Then move the cursor outside of the ERT and insert the matrix. That's all

Comment: @Herbert Okay, then I have discovered a bug. If I type `\array....{2.2}` *manually* then it works. But if I copy and paste `\array....{2.2}` then the `\def` will be converted and preceded by `\global\long`. Right?

Comment: @e-birk: Copy and paste with everything bewtween `\[ ... \]` works without a problem. LyX 2.0.3

Comment: @Herbert I copy only `\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}` from a plain text editor. "Insert > Math > Display Formula", Crtl-L, Backspace (to remove the ``\`` - it does not matter whether now or later), Ctrl-V. What does "View Source" show? For me, `\arraycolsep=1.4pt\global\long\def\arraystretch{2.2}`. LyX 2.0.5.1

Comment: The line `\arraycolsep=1.4pt\def\arraystretch{2.2}` must come immediately before `\begin{array}...`

Comment: This solution does not work well for anything with matrices in them unfortunately. Any way to exclude matrix spacing from this?

Answer (score 13):

Use the `alignat` environment from the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.  You can also adjust the space between lines with the `\setstretch` command from the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
{\setstretch{2.25}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x(1)   &=\frac{x(0)}{1}    &&= x(0)\\
x(2)   &=\frac{x(1)}{2}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{2}\\
x(3)   &=\frac{x(2)}{3}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{2.3}\\
x(4)   &=\frac{x(3)}{4}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{4!}\\
\vdots &                   && \\
x(n)   &=\frac{x(n-1)}{n!} &&= \frac{x(0)}{n!}
\end{alignat*}}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of completeness, you can also adjust the vertical space between two lines of the `alignat*` environment (this is also true for the `align*` environment) by specifying the spacing to use inside square brackets (for example `[.5cm]`) right after the newline symbol `\\`. Note that this value can also be a negative measurement if you want to reduce the vertical space between two lines. This is especially useful to *individually* correct the spacing between lines, such as when the line heights differ from one line to another (for example, all lines contain a fraction except one).

The following example is not made to be pretty or practical, but merely to show an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
{\setstretch{2.25}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x(1)   &=\frac{x(0)}{1}    &&= x(0)\\[.5cm]
x(2)   &=\frac{x(1)}{2}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{2}\\[2cm]
x(3)   &=\frac{x(2)}{3}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{2.3}\\[-3mm]
x(4)   &=\frac{x(3)}{4}    &&= \frac{x(0)}{4!}\\
\vdots &                   && \\
x(n)   &=\frac{x(n-1)}{n!} &&= \frac{x(0)}{n!}
\end{alignat*}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output for code above.]

Answer (score 1):

In LyX, I added `\usepackage{amsmath}` to Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble. Then instead of using `array` environment, which generates

[image]

I change to `aligned` environment, which generates a much better looking equation array and spacing

[image]

There are other discussions on the left alignments that seem very complicated. But what I found in my case is that, if I start a cell with the = sign, the LaTeX compiler will figure out how to align to the left.

Comment: You could achieve a similar result simply by using \displaystyle.