# Fractions with `\dfrac` cause compile error

Tags: errors, lyx, fractions

I'm new to LyX. I'm writing my next homework with it to give it a try. My example code is below:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is an expression with dfrac:

\[ f(x) = \dfrac{2}{x} \]
\end{document}
```

Under [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103508/7493), they offered me to use `\dfrac` fractions for a better view. However, using `dfrac` causes compiler error like below:

[image: Compiler Error]

I thought this error with `dfrac` may be due to not using the `amsmath` package. I went to `Menu > Document > Settings > Math Options`, I unchecked `Use AMS math package automatically` and I checked `Use AMS math package`. LyX added `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{amssymb}` lines into the source code. Now when I try to preview my article in PDF format, it gives `LaTeX Error: File 'amsmath.sty' not found.` error.

I used to use online Latex editors, then copy screen shot of their output and paste it into MS Word. It was so simple doing that way. Now all these packages, uneditable source code, and all these complexity for writing a simple fraction is making me too frustrated. I have started to question if I did the right thing with switching to LyX. Because those online editors perfectly displaying that `dfrac` fraction in my example.

How do I write a simple `dfrac` fraction after opening a new article from `Menu > File > New` in a fresh LyX 2.0.5.1 installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to documents->settings->math-> enable amsmath

Comment: When I try to preview it says "LaTeX Error: File 'amsmath.sty' not found.".

Comment: @hkBattousai: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: @hkBattousai: the `\dfrac` in your example has no effect, the equation is alread set in displastyle. However, I cannot believe that amsnmath isn't installed. What system do you have?

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I installed LyX a few days ago. It installed packages during installations from a default online repository. I'm updating packages by MiKTeX update tool again at the moment.

Comment: Result: It only found update to a package named "fontspec". Then my code suddenly started to work. I don't know why but it now works. I did make any change in a bit other than running the update tool. I have a hard time understanding this LyX editor...