# LyX: use align environment instead of the default eqnarray

Tags: equations, lyx

I use LyX and it uses `eqnarray` for multiline equations, which is [bad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Is there a way to make LyX use `align` instead?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use `amsmath`.  take a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103695/579

Comment: amsmath is enabled via the math options, but I still get the eqnarray. Is there some option I need to activate?

Comment: Is Insert > Math > AMS align environment what you want?

Comment: I hand't noticed that, thanks. Is there a convenient way to convert all my current eqnarray equations to align?
Also, is there a way to make "ctrl+enter" start an align instead of eqnarray?

Comment: To convert, I believe you would need to use find/replace in a text editor (the .lyx file is just a text file). I'm not sure this is a good idea. To get ctrl+enter to start align, go to Document > Settings > Math and set amsmath to "load always". Then do "ctrl+enter". It should now do align (this won't convert old ones to align though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LyX has the [behavior](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2543) by which if AMS is not loaded, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> does `eqnarray`. If it is loaded, it does `align`. So the solution is to go to Document > Settings > Math and click on "load always" for `amsmath`. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> creates an `align`. You can convert from `eqnarray` to `align` by right-clicking the environment, and selecting AMS environment > AMS align.

Comment: Converting from `eqnarray` to `align` (and vice versa) works for me in Lyx 2.1.4 (see http://imgur.com/FpRofgV). Is it possible that this bug has been fixed?

Comment: @Deve indeed I think you are right. We just marked the bug as fixed.

Comment: I edited a bit following a suggested edit, and based on the previous comments. Hope it's not too bad now, do edit if you think it is.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. definitely an improvement. Thanks!