# Making matrix with enough spacing in Beamer ( Latex )

Tags: beamer

[image: Matrix]
Hello seniors. Can anybody tell me how to code this matrix with enough spacing between them like shown in the figure.I am a beginner.Kindly help me

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces what you have shown, and please explain what **specifically** is your problem. It will be much easier for us to help you when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sir . I have written the code but there is not enough space between rows and column. It looks so congested

Comment: Then please edit your question and include the code.

Comment: Will you help me with this ? I will upload the code in a while?

Comment: If the problem is with latex, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103508/adjusting-space-between-array-rows-and-columns.  If the problem is specific to beamer, The usual answer is "Don't do that in beamer."

Comment: Sir I need to do this in beamer. I need to do this. Kindly help. Please help me. I have an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shorthand notation

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and each entry of $A$ admits the value
given by \[A_{jk}=(2)^j(3)^{-k}.\] Then, \[\det{A} = 0.\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir for posting . But it is showing an error during compliation. " This is not a valid pdf document "