# How to increase space between rows in begin array equation?

Tags: equations, arrays

I want to increase space between rows of this vector `\overrightarrow{grad}` in the equation below:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
 \nonumber \vec F=\vec P=\left(
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  0\\0\\ _mg
 \end{array}
\right)_{(\vec i, \vec j, \vec k)} \hspace{0.2cm}\textrm{ et }\hspace{0.2cm}
\overrightarrow{grad}V(\sum)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \left.\frac{\partial V_x(\sum) }{\partial x}\right.\\ \left.\frac{\partial V_y(\sum) }{\partial y}\right.\\ \left.\frac{\partial V_z(\sum) }{\partial z}\right.
\end{array}
\right)_{(\vec i, \vec j, \vec k)}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Do not use `eqnarray`. It gives bad horizontal spacing around the alignment points (which you have not here, anyway). This being said, you can add to your preamble, say `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`.

Comment: thank you, i find reply to my question, in this answer [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103508/adjusting-space-between-array-rows-and-columns)

Comment: If it is  for a too high content touching the above and/or below row, the best solution, in my opinion, consists in using the `cellspace` package.

Comment: thank you @Bernard, i used `{\setstretch{1.75}
\begin{alignat*}{2} ........ \end{alignat*}}` by including the `setspace` package, it work well for me.

Comment: It's another possible solution. Take care of the spacing on entering and leaving the environment, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `eqnarray`, even less for a single equation.

Also there are some strange things in your input, for instance `\left.` and `\right.` that only add (unwanted) spaces and `\sum` for what should probably be `\Sigma`.

Better use `pmatrix` instead of `array`; I also defined a shorthand for partial derivatives.

For the “touching” fractions, add some vertical space as shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\overrightarrow{\mathrm{grad}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\vec{F}=\vec{P}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ {}_mg
\end{pmatrix}_{(\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k})}
\quad\text{et}\quad
\grad V(\Sigma)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\pder{V_x(\Sigma)}{x} \\[1ex]
\pder{V_y(\Sigma)}{y} \\[1ex]
\pder{V_z(\Sigma)}{z}
\end{pmatrix}_{(\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k})}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]